# I want create shortcut

Tags: android

I create shortcut when open the app but the problem is that create a shortcut always that open the app if I open the app 20 time  then creates 20 shortcuts

I need that only create one shortcut the first open not more

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ShortcutIcon();

   }




private void ShortcutIcon(){

    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Whatsapp Imagenes");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.icono));
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On pre-JB android versions, you can try this:

```
addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
```

Otherwise, you can just uninstall and reinstall the shortcut:

```
intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

More info [here](http://codinggeekorg.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/android-home-screen-shortcuts-part-iii-remove-shortcuts/).

Comment: addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
this work good but can I eliminate the toast that say ShortCut "Whatsapp Imagen" already exists

Comment: @Gatiko06 I don't think you can.

Comment: addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false); doesn't work on devices above API 14

Comment: Yes as stated in my answer this will not work on API level 14 and above. Use the 2nd method which consists in removing the shortcut before installing it again.

Comment: Why always says that you click icon, jumb error "the application is not installed"

Answer (score 0):

You can store a flag in preference manager to mark whether you've created the shortcut. This can be achieved by

```
SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("shortcut_created", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
if (prefs.getBoolean("shortcut_created", false)) 
{ 
    // if shortcut has not been created, create your shortcut here
    ...
    // once shortcut is created, mark the preference so the next time it does not 
    // create the shortcut again 

    editor.putBoolean("shortcut_created", true);
}
```

Comment: 1/ You could use the activity context, so just call getSharedPreferences("shortcut_created", 0);

2/ You need to commit: editor.putBoolean("shortcut_created", true).commit();

3/ Be aware, if someone clears the data of your app this will not work.

Comment: yes, you could use the activity context like @AmokraneChentir mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.You can use SharePreferences to check if the App is firstly starting. More information check this:

http://pulse7.net/android/